# Dúvidas com estrutura condicional

Tags: javascript, if

Estou com um problema na minha estrutura condicional, onde está sendo exibido todos os resultados do `if`.

**Quais são as minhas dificuldades:**

- 1) Por que isto está ocorrendo?
- 2) O que fazer para resolver?

**Segue o meu código:**

```js
var valor1 =Number(prompt("Digite hum numero: "))
var valor2 =Number(prompt("Digite hum numero: "))
var valor3 =Number(prompt("Digite hum numero: "))
if(valor1 >= valor2 || valor1 >= valor3){
   alert("O valor maior é "+valor1)

}
if(valor2 >= valor1 || valor2 >= valor3){
   alert("O valor maior é "+valor2)

}
if(valor3 >= valor1 || valor3 >= valor2){
   alert("O valor maior é "+valor3)

}
```

Comment: A minha resposta ficou adequada e de fácil entendimento para você?

Comment: você está mexendo com operadores de curto-circuito, uma das partes que for avaliada,a outra será ignorada e resulta-se em TRUE no caso do OU. 
E não entendi muito bem a proposta do código.

Comment: Vc quer SOMENTE saber qual o número maior ou importa saber também qual deles é maior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa estudar mais sobre raciocínio lógico, para depois praticar nos algoritmos...

Abordarei **2 assuntos** para você compreender melhor, os quais são:

- **1) Tabela-Verdade**
- **2) Operadores Lógicos**

**O que é Tabela-Verdade?**

> Tabela-verdade, tabela de verdade ou tabela veritativa é um tipo de tabela matemática usada em lógica para determinar se uma fórmula é válida ou se um sequente é correto.

**O que são Operadores Lógicos?**

> Operador lógico, assim como um operador aritmético, é uma classe de operação sobre variáveis ou elementos pré-definidos. `AND`, `NAND`, `OR`, `XOR` e `NOT` são os principais operadores lógicos, base para a construção de sistemas digitais e da Lógica proposicional, e também muito usado em linguagem de programação. Os operadores `AND`, `NAND`, `OR` e `XOR` são operadores binários, ou seja, necessitam de dois elementos, enquanto o `NOT` é unário. Na computação, esses elementos são normalmente variáveis binárias, cujos possíveis valores atribuídos são `0` ou `1`. Porém, a lógica empregada para essas variáveis serve também para sentenças (frases) da linguagem humana, onde se esta for **verdade corresponde ao valor** `1`, e se for **falsa corresponde ao valor** `0`.

Agora, vamos a prática tudo bem? Abordarei dando exemplos simples e das principais portas lógicas com suas respectivas tabela-verdade para você entender melhor a lógica dos mesmos.

**Ilustração das principais portas lógicas e suas respectivas tabela-verdade:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Porta Lógica** `NOT`:

> Esta porta ela é uma porta de negação, ou seja, se você perceber em sua **tabela-verdade**, quando a entrada `A` recebe `0`(falso-desligado) ela transforma a saída em `1`(verdadeiro-ligado) e quando ela recebe `1` ela transforma a saída em `0`. Exemplo em algoritmo:

```
if(!isLarge){
} else {}
```

> O que estou querendo dizer com este código é o seguinte: Se for diferente de **grande** entre neste `if`, senão entre no `else`.

**Porta Lógica** `AND`:

> Esta porta verifica a condição das duas entradas, **para entrar na determinada condição as duas entradas devem por obrigatoriedade serem verdadeiras**, tanto que você pode analisar na sua **tabela-verdade**, ela só possui a saída `1` (verdade) quando as duas entradas possuem os valores `1` e `1`. Exemplo em algoritmo:

```
if(isLarge && tamanho == 50.00){
} else{}
```

> O que estou querendo dizer com este código é o seguinte: Se for **grande** e o **tamanho** for igual a **50cm** entre no `if`, senão entre no `else`.

**Porta Lógica** `OR`**:**

> Esta porta verifica a condição das duas entradas, porém ela é diferente da `AND`, pois **para ser verdade pelo menos uma das entradas devem possuir o valor** `1`, você pode observar em sua tabela que ela somente é verdade quando uma das entradas possuem o valor `1` ou as duas possuem o valor `1`. Exemplo em algoritmo:

```
if(isLarge || tamanho == 50.00){
} else{}
```

> O que estou querendo dizer com este código é o seguinte: Se for **grande** e o se o **tamanho** for igual a **50cm** entre no `if`, senão entre no `else`. Independentemente se não for **grande** e o **tamanho** for igual a **50cm** ela entrada no if, se for **grande** e o **tamanho** for diferente de **50cm** ela entrada no `if`, caso não for **grande** e o **tamanho** não for igual a **50cm** ela entrada no `else`.

Answer (score 4):

Usar o `&&` ou `||` jamais obterá um resultado adequado a sua condicional.
Você também pode usar isso:

```
Math.max(2,5,8,10,14)
```

Que vai retornar o maior valor informado.

Teste em seu console no browser.

Com prompt:

```
var valor1 =Number(prompt("Digite hum numero: "))
var valor2 =Number(prompt("Digite hum numero: "))
var valor3 =Number(prompt("Digite hum numero: "))

Math.max(valor1,valor2,valor3)]
```

Digitamos 10, 20 e 5.

Retorno: 20

Comment: Meu muito obrigado, estou aprendendo JS na faculdade, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Meu caro... ficaria assim:

var valor1 =1
    var valor2 =2
    var valor3 =3

Math.max(valor1,valor2,valor3)
Resultado: 3

Comment: @lucas_botina Bem-vindo ao SOpt. Depois dê uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Uma das boas práticas do site é dar upvote nas respostas que te ajudaram de alguma forma (mesmo se não fosse vc o autor da pergunta) e aceite como resposta correta a resposta que mais se adeque à sua pergunta. :)

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente, sua lógica permite a execução de todos os `if` para a verificação e que apenas uma condição de maior ou igual execute o conteúdo da condição. Vamos supor que o usuário entre com os números `valor1 = 4`, `valor2 = 2` e `valor3 = 6`. Assim temos:

`if(valor1 >= valor2 || valor1 >= valor3)` temos que 4 é maior que 2, mas que 4 não é maior que 6. Mesmo assim, a condição é atendida, por causa do `||` (ou) que você colocou na condição, permitindo essa aceitação e mostrando esse alerta.

`if(valor2 >= valor1 || valor2 >= valor3)` temos que 2 não é maior que 4 e que 2 não é maior que 6. Essa condição é ignorada.

`if(valor3 >= valor1 || valor3 >= valor2)` temos que 6 é maior que 2 e 6 é maior que 4, portanto sendo essa a condição verdadeira do código(6 é o maior número), e também mostra o alerta, executando assim duas de suas condições.

Então, o certo seria você fazer essa verificação com o operador lógico `&&` (e), que permite que essas condições não sejam aceitas apenas se uma for verdade, mas sim apenas se o número for realmente o maior. Segue correção:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var valor1 =Number(prompt("Digite um numero: "))
var valor2 =Number(prompt("Digite um numero: "))
var valor3 =Number(prompt("Digite um numero: "))
if(valor1 >= valor2 && valor1 >= valor3){
    alert("O valor maior é "+valor1)

}
if(valor2 >= valor1 && valor2 >= valor3){
    alert("O valor maior é "+valor2)

}
if (valor3 >= valor1 && valor3 >= valor2){
    alert("O valor maior é "+valor3)

}
</script>
```

Comment: Boa. Mas seria interessante usar o `else` já que se o maior valor for encontrado, não precisa mais passar pelos outros `if`s :)

Comment: Verdade. Tentei fazer o mais simples possível e esqueci que poderia melhorar o código

Answer (score 0):

Além do problema em usar o operador `||` (or) em vez do `&&` (and), onde o `&&` significa que ambas as condições devem ser *true*, neste caso seria melhor usar um `if else` e um `else` (caso não queira usar `Math.max()` e manter a estrutura de `if`'s), pois não é necessário passar por cada `if` se você quer que apenas 1 conjunto de condições seja satisfeita.

Por exemplo, no primeiro `if` você já "mata" a questão verificando se o `valor1` é maior que os outros dois valores:

```
if(valor1 >= valor2 && valor1 >= valor3){
  alert("O valor maior é "+valor1)
}else if(valor2 >= valor3){
  alert("O valor maior é "+valor2)
}else{
  alert("O valor maior é "+valor3)
}
```

Se `valor1` for maior ou igual a `valor2` e `valor3` a verificação irá ignorar os dois outros blocos (`else if` e `else`) já encerrando a verificação nas primeiras condições.

Se `valor1` for menor que `valor2` e maior ou igual a `valor3`, não satisfará o primeiro `if` passando pro `else if`, logo, já é descartado que `valor1` é o maior número, então, se `valor2` for maior ou igual a `valor3`, a verificação acaba aí, sendo `valor2` o maior  número se ele for maior que `valor3` ou então, se for igual a `valor3`, ambos são os valores maiores. Agora, se `valor2` for menor que `valor3`, então irá cair no `else` porque nenhum dos dois `if`'s foram atendidos, e com isso `valor3` é o maior número **ou** `valor1` e `valor3` são iguais e são os maiores números.

**Testes de mesa:**

```
valor1 = 1
valor2 = 2
valor3 = 3

     if: condição 1 = falso, porque valor1 não é igual nem maior que valor2
                      (nem precisa verificar a segunda condição)
else if: falso, porque 2 não é maior nem igual a valor3, logo, obrigatoriamente
         irá cair no else

> resultado: número maior = 3

------------------------------

valor1 = 3
valor2 = 2
valor3 = 1

     if: condição 1 = verdadeiro, porque valor1 é maior ou igual que valor2
         condição 2 = verdadeiro, porque valor1 é maior ou igual que valor3
else if: ignorado
   else: ignorado

> resultado: número maior = 3

------------------------------

valor1 = 1
valor2 = 2
valor3 = 1

     if: condição 1 = falso, porque valor1 é menor que valor2
                      (nem precisa verificar a segunda condição)
else if: verdadeiro, porque valor2 é maior que valor3
   else: ignorado

> resultado: número maior = 2

------------------------------

valor1 = 1
valor2 = 1
valor3 = 1

     if: condição 1 = verdadeiro, porque valor1 é igual a valor2
         condição 2 = verdadeiro, porque valor1 é igual a valor3
else if: ignorado
   else: ignorado

> resultado: número maior = 1

------------------------------

valor1 = 1
valor2 = 2
valor3 = 2

     if: condição 1 = falso, porque valor1 é menor que valor2
         (nem precisa verificar a segunda condição)
else if: verdadeiro, porque valor2 é igual a valor3
   else: ignorado

> resultado: número maior = 2
```

**Teste:**

```js
var valor1 =Number(prompt("Digite hum numero: "))
var valor2 =Number(prompt("Digite hum numero: "))
var valor3 =Number(prompt("Digite hum numero: "))

if(valor1 >= valor2 && valor1 >= valor3){
  alert("O valor maior é "+valor1)
}else if(valor2 >= valor3){
  alert("O valor maior é "+valor2)
}else{
  alert("O valor maior é "+valor3)
}
```